# Problem with ParameterFitting:""The function value...is not a list of real numbers..."

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, parameters

I'm trying to use the data:

```
    In[33]:= data = Transpose[{datat, datax}]

Out[33]= {{1, 83956}, {2, 83959}, {3, 83959}, {4, 83964}, {5, 
  83966}, {6, 83968}, {7, 83970}, {8, 83975}, {9, 83976}, {10, 
  83990}, {11, 84010}, {12, 84011}, {13, 84018}, {14, 84024}, {15, 
  84029}, {16, 84038}, {17, 84044}, {18, 84054}, {19, 84063}, {20, 
  84063}, {21, 84063}, {22, 84063}, {23, 84081}, {24, 84084}, {25, 
  84095}, {26, 84102}, {27, 84103}, {28, 84106}, {29, 84106}, {30, 
  84123}, {31, 84128}, {32, 84146}, {33, 84154}, {34, 84161}, {35, 
  84160}, {36, 84171}, {37, 84177}, {38, 84186}, {39, 84191}, {40, 
  84195}, {41, 84198}, {42, 84209}, {43, 84216}, {44, 84228}, {45, 
  84286}, {46, 84335}, {47, 84378}, {48, 84422}, {49, 84458}, {50, 
  84494}, {51, 84494}, {52, 84553}, {53, 84572}, {54, 84624}, {55, 
  84653}, {56, 84673}, {57, 84701}, {58, 84725}, {59, 84743}, {60, 
  84757}, {61, 84780}, {62, 84785}, {63, 84816}, {64, 84830}, {65, 
  84838}, {66, 84857}, {67, 84871}, {68, 84889}, {69, 84917}, {70, 
  84950}, {71, 84992}, {72, 84992}, {73, 85071}, {74, 85117}, {75, 
  85117}, {76, 85226}, {77, 85246}, {78, 85327}, {79, 85402}, {80, 
  85418}, {81, 85503}, {82, 85622}, {83, 85708}, {84, 85906}, {85, 
  86045}, {86, 86202}, {87, 86381}, {88, 86570}, {89, 86783}, {90, 
  86990}, {91, 87213}, {92, 87489}, {93, 87655}, {94, 87827}, {95, 
  87985}, {96, 88099}, {97, 88206}, {98, 88328}, {99, 88460}, {100, 
  88580}, {101, 88672}, {102, 88793}, {103, 88906}, {104, 
  88958}, {105, 89045}, {106, 89144}, {107, 89214}, {108, 
  89279}, {109, 89375}, {110, 89441}, {111, 89494}, {112, 
  89527}, {113, 89567}, {114, 89616}, {115, 89654}, {116, 
  89695}, {117, 89718}, {118, 89752}, {119, 89784}, {120, 
  89814}, {121, 89836}, {122, 89863}, {123, 89895}, {124, 
  89914}, {125, 89933}, {126, 89953}, {127, 89986}, {128, 
  90008}, {129, 90025}}
```

To find parameters in the differential equation model that give the best fit:

```
    pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
   Ii[1.] + S[1.] + R[1.] + F[1.] == 1411780000,
   S'[x] == -R0*F[x]/alpha,
   R'[x] == gamma*Ii[x],
   Ii'[x] == F[x]/alpha + r*F[x] - gamma*Ii[x],
   F'[x] == -F[x]/alpha + R0*F[x]/alpha - r*F[x],
   Ii[1.] == 1900,
   R[1.] == 78504,
   F[1.] == 1900}, R + Ii + F, {x, 0, 150}, {alpha, R0, gamma, r}]

    fit = FindFit[data, 
  pfun[alpha, R0, gamma, r][x], {{alpha, 1.}, R0, gamma, r}, x]
```

however I got an error code:

```
 FindFit::nrlnum: The function value {<<1>>} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {129} at {alpha,R0,gamma,r} = {1.,1.,1.,1.}.
```

How can I solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One of the most important things when fitting such a complicated function to data is to provide a good initial guess for the parameters. Do you know the approximate values of the parameters (alpha, R0, gamma, r)? At least their order of magnitude? Are they all positive?

Comment: Approximately, alpha=14, R0>0, 0<gamma<1, r>0. But I can't find a way to express these using mathematica.

Comment: I have troubles getting the curve to match your datapoints. Are you sure your ODEs describe the whole range of your data? Can you double check the ODEs and the hard-coded parameters. Take a look at my answer and try it yourself.

Comment: It's worth noting that your equations are linear, and so Mathematica can find an exact solution for them without invoking numerical techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @Michael's solution, you can also provide an extra algebraic equation in your system of ODEs:

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
    Ii[1.] + S[1.] + R[1.] + F[1.] == 1411780000, 
    S'[x] == -R0*F[x]/alpha, R'[x] == gamma*Ii[x], 
    Ii'[x] == F[x]/alpha + r*F[x] - gamma*Ii[x], 
    F'[x] == -F[x]/alpha + R0*F[x]/alpha - r*F[x], Ii[1.] == 1900, 
    R[1.] == 78504, F[1.] == 1900,
    T[x] == R[x] + Ii[x] + F[x]
}, T, {x, 0, 150}, {alpha, R0, gamma, r}];
```

Now, as I have mentioned in the comments, I have troubles finding the parameters to get a sigmoid-like curve, described by your datapoints. The solution seems to be either exponential-like or hyperbolic-like. Try it yourself:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[Evaluate@pfun[alpha, R0, gamma, r]@x, {x, 0, 250},
   PlotRange -> {50000,100000}], ListPlot[data]], {{alpha, 14}, 
  12, 15}, {R0, 0, 2}, {gamma, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

With pfun from @domen's answer , `NonlinearModelFit` allows to implement several constraints and evaluates an answer (`Method -> "NMinimize"` doesn't need starting values)

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, {pfun[alpha, R0, gamma,r][x], 
alpha > 0, 0 < gamma < 1, R0 > 0, r > 0}, 
{alpha , R0, gamma, r}, x, 
Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

But the fit is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to arise from the fact that you're using `ParametricNDSolve` to return a result for the anonymous function `R + Ii + F`, rather than a single anonymous function.  This means that when you provide this object with a set of parameters, it returns something of the form

```
(InterpolatingFunction[data] + InterpolatingFunction[data] +InterpolatingFunction[data])[x]
```

rather than

```
InterpolatingFunction[data][x] + InterpolatingFunction[data][x]+InterpolatingFunction[data][x]
```

as one might expect. There's probably a slick "functional programming" way to fix this using `Through` or the like, but I'm not enough of a functional programming boffin to know how to do it in this context.  (I look forward to seeing if/how other users manage to make this work.)

That said, it's easy enough to recast your ODEs so that they return $f(x) \equiv R(x) + I_i(x) + F(x)$ instead:

```
eqns = {Ii[1.] + S[1.] + R[1.] + F[1.] == 1411780000, 
  S'[x] == -R0*F[x]/alpha, R'[x] == gamma*Ii[x], 
  Ii'[x] == F[x]/alpha + r*F[x] - gamma*Ii[x], 
  F'[x] == -F[x]/alpha + R0*F[x]/alpha - r*F[x], Ii[1.] == 1900, 
  R[1.] == 78504, F[1.] == 1900};
eqns2 = eqns /. {F[x_] -> f[x] - Ii[x] - R[x], 
  Derivative[n_][F][x_] -> D[f[x] - Ii[x] - R[x], {x, n}]}
pfun2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns2, 
  f, {x, 0, 150}, {alpha, R0, gamma, r}]
fit = FindFit[data, pfun2[alpha, R0, gamma, r][x], {{alpha, 1.}, R0, gamma, r}, x]
```

This, at least, does not return an error when executed, though it is taking an awfully long time to run on my computer.  Providing better initial guesses will no doubt help.